# OSError: [WinError 8] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command in yolo

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, yolo

I am trying to create a project on real time vehicle classification using yolo model. when executing this command

```
python flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --train`
```

this error pops up:

```
mm = mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), bytes, access=acc, offset=start)
OSError: [WinError 8] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
```

Source which I've used to train can be found from https://github.com/markjay4k/YOLO-series

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. What is your question?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `anaconda` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: How to solve this error?